Twilio requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ap1.twilio.com', port=443):
I am trying to send a custom sms to a user via twilio but getting ssl error
This is how I am doing. When I try this code
message = twilio_client.messages.create(
    body=f"Your OTP is: {new_otp}",
    from_=settings.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    to=to_phone_number
)

where twilio_client is
twilio_client = Client(
    settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, region="ap1"
)

I get the following error after this running this part of the code
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ap1.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
    with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC871e4afa1d16f5f1a892a7af250eabf2/Messages.json 
    (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
    certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch,
    certificate is not valid for 'api.ap1.twilio.com'. (_ssl.c:1007)")))

based on online research I checked the url that this part is referring that is
https://api.ap1.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC871e4afa1d16f5f1a892a7af250eabf2/Messages.json
but when I check with Postman it gives me 404 not found response

there is mismatch in hostname and certificate invalid as indicated in error.Please refer this documentation https://help.twilio.com/articles/360007853433-Troubleshooting-Certificate-Errors-from-the-Twilio-REST-API

If I understand the pattern in the SANs correctly, the only supported regions are us1, au1, and ie1. See this article

Found the solution, I just removed region="ap1" from the twilio_client now it works correctly so instead of
twilio_client = Client(
    settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, region="ap1"
)

use
twilio_client = Client(
    settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
)

